# How to solve $(x^3y^n+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+2y = 0$ implicitly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $n$ be a real number, not necessary an integer, how to solve $$(x^3y^n+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+2y = 0$$ implicitly?

That is, express the solution in the form $f(x,y)=C$ for some appropriate function $f$.

I think I only need a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x^3y^n+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+2y = 0$$
Consider $x'$ instead of $y'$
$$(x^3y^n+x)+2yx' = 0$$
It's Bernoulli's equation
$$2yx'+x = -x^3y^n$$
$$(\sqrt y x)'= -\frac 12x^3y^{n-1/2}$$
It's separable:
$$\dfrac {d(x\sqrt y )}{(x\sqrt y )^3}= -\frac 12y^{n-2}dy$$
Integrate.